# how to keep the checkbox checked if it has been already checked using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a input checkbox field, when i `check` the box the functions work fine but after refresh the tick mark disappears in the box.
So can i get the tick mark be `true` if it has been already selected and the data saved in other page.

HTML:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="pin.checked" (change)="fav(pin)" style="margin-top: 10px;"></td>
```

TS:

```
loadAllPins() {
  var favouratePins = this.storage.favouratePins; 
  console.log(favouratePins);
  this.ApiService
      .getAllPins(this.guide_id)
      .subscribe(
        pins  => {
          if(favouratePins && favouratePins.length > 0) {
            pins.data.map(function(pin) {
              favouratePins.map(function(item) {
                if(pin._id == item._id) {
                  pin.checked = true;
                }
              })
            })            
          }
          this.pins = pins.data;

        },error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

in the first page what all i have checked had been and saved in another page, so the items which have been stored already in another page contents needs to be marked checked in the first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question you are sending `pin_id` as `data` to `api` so, you need to compare `pin_id` instead of `_id`

Here you are sending `pin_id`
var data = {
      "user_id":user_id,
      "pin_id":pin._id
}

So you should use,

```
 if(favouratePins && favouratePins.length > 0) {
    pins.data.map(function(pin) {
      favouratePins.map(function(item) {
       if(pin._id == item._id) {
            pin.checked = true;
        }
       })
      })            
     }
     this.pins = pins.data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `checked` attribute.

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" [checked]="pin.checked" [(ngModel)]="pin.checked" (change)="fav(pin)" style="margin-top: 10px;">
</td>
```